# Back&: Compute Units

Tags: backand

I'm working with the Backand with an Ionic mobile app that I'm developing. It's a data intensive app so I'm wanting to make sure doing my interactions most efficiently.  Is there some parameters documented somewhere that tells me what are better ways to make calls?  Like I'm assuming a Query using MySQL does requires more Compute Units than a REST GET call with filter but how much less?  Thanks for any help as I haven't found any documentation on Backand Compute Units.